# I need help finishing this proof using the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)\geq g(a)$ and $f(b) \leq g(b)$. Prove $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ for at least one $x_0$ in $[a,b]$.

Here's what I have so far:

Let $h$ be a continuous function where $h = f -g$

Since $h(b)=f(b)-g(b)\leq 0$, and $h(a)=f(a)-g(a)\geq 0$, then $h(b)\leq 0 \leq h(a)$ is true.

So, by IVT there exists some $y$ such that...

And that's where I need help. I read what the IVT is, but I could use some help explaining how it applies here, and why it finishes the proof. Thank you!

Comment: By IVT there exists an $x_0\in [a,b]$ such that $h(x_0)=0$. What does $h(x_0)=0$ mean in terms of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Would that mean $f(x_0) - g(x_0) = 0$?

Comment: By definition $h(x_0) = f(x_0) - g(x_0)$ so ...

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. But since you now have $f(x_0)-g(x_0)=0$, you're done. Just a slight rearrangement, and you have exactly what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: Okay, and we're just allowed to assume that by IVT?

Comment: That is what IVT says: $h$ goes from being positive at $a$ to being negative at $b$, and IVT then guarantees the existence of a point where it's $0$. $h$ being zero at some point means that $f$ and $g$ are equal at that point, since you defined $h$ to have that exact property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists some $y \in (a,b)$ such that $h(y) = 0$. So $f(y) = g(y)$. The other case $a=b$ is trivial.